# How to bloom effect in WebGPU without FBO?

Tags: post-processing, webgpu

In WebGL we are able to render to framebufferobject and then use it as a texture so that another shader module is able to load it and [calculate bloom effect](https://webplatform.github.io/docs/tutorials/post-processing_with_webgl/). In WebGPU we no longer get framebufferobject. The responsibilities of FBO are split into several feature. Now how do we perform bloom effect?

Comment: FBO's are a native feature of WebGPU, they're just called a "GPURenderPassDescriptor". The info you would have specified in an FBO is specified in the GPURenderPassDescriptor that you pass to [beginRenderPass](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GPUCommandEncoder/beginRenderPass)

Comment: also got some useful examples https://webgpu.github.io/webgpu-samples/samples/imageBlur#main.ts on combining renderPipeline and computePipeline.

Answer (score 0):

*Answering my own question*. I did some experiments in
https://github.com/Triadica/lagopus.ts/pull/14 and the prototype worked.

However the prototype is really SLOW at current.

I used multiple passes,

1. render shapes to a texture,
2. screen out bright pixels to new texture,
3. move data to pingpong texture,
4. pingpong rendering maybe,
5. mix data and render into a real canvas.

since we don't have FBO now, I created a texture for holding render results:

```js
let texture = device.createTexture({
  size: [width, height],
  format: "bgra8unorm",
  usage: GPUTextureUsage.COPY_SRC | GPUTextureUsage.RENDER_ATTACHMENT | GPUTextureUsage.TEXTURE_BINDING,
});
```

then I reused large part of code from https://webgpu.github.io/webgpu-samples/samples/imageBlur#main.ts which was used for blur, to make bloom effect. That made the prototype. For the demo of blur, it looks like https://r.tiye.me/Triadica/lagopus.ts-220409/ .